# How to play stream aacp running background on Android

Tags: android, service, stream, aac

I am searching for days how to run in the background a stream Shoutcast whose content / type: **audio / AACP**. 
At the moment, I'm getting the run stream using the library [aacdecoder-android](http://code.google.com/p/aacdecoder-android/), but do not understand how to use a service to leave the stream in the background.
Has anyone used something like that?

Code:

**MainActivity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public AACPlayer mp;
    private Toast myToast;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private ImageParser mImageParser;

    private WebView publicidadecapa;

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Sair");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle().toString() == "Sair") {
            finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.maintab);       

        mp = new AACPlayer(new RadioCallBack(this));                
        ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
        loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        ImageView playButton = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.playButton);
        playButton.setTag("1");
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                ImageView playButton = (ImageView) arg0;
                ConnectivityManager cm =
                        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

                if ( cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() == null || !cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting() ) {
                    if (myToast == null) {
                        myToast = Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Verifique a conexão com a internet", 5000);
                    }
                    myToast.setDuration(5000);
                    myToast.show();
                    return;
                }

                if (playButton.getTag() == "1" && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting() ) {

                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_menustop);
                    playButton.setTag("0");
                    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
                    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Conectando...");


                    mp.playAsync( "http://voxsc1.somafm.com:9002/" );

                } else if ( playButton.getTag() == "0" ) {                  

                    playButton.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
                    loading.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_menuplay);
                    playButton.setTag("1");

                    mp.stop();
                }                                               

            }           
        });        

        final AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        

        SeekBar volumeControl = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.volumeControl);
        volumeControl.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeControl.setProgress(audioManager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
        volumeControl.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


            }

            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar arg0) {


            }

            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar arg0, int arg1, boolean arg2) {
                audioManager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, arg1,0);
                if(arg1 == 0) {
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume2);
                } else {
                    ((ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2)).setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_volume1);
                }
            }
        });        
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

    }
    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        if (this.isFinishing()) {
            //mp.stop();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onStart()
    {
        super.onStart();

        // your code
    }


    public Object fetch(String address) throws MalformedURLException,IOException {
        URL url = new URL(address);
        Object content = url.getContent();
        return content;
    }


    private Boolean isOnline()  {
        ConnectivityManager cm = 
                (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(ni != null && ni.isConnected())
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    /* Abrir em uma nova aba o link da publicidade */
    public class MyWebClient extends WebViewClient{
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            //Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
            Context context = view.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,OpenSiteWebView.class);

            Bundle parametros = new Bundle();
            parametros.putString("url", url);

            intent.putExtras(parametros);

            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

**RadioCallBack:**

```
public class RadioCallBack implements PlayerCallback {

    private MainActivity activity;

    public RadioCallBack(MainActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public void playerException(Throwable arg0) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {                    
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(activity, "O stream pode estar offline! Tente novamente mais tarde", 50000).show();

                ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
                loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ImageView playButton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                playButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.btn_menuplay);
                playButton.setTag("1");
                ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Pressione PLAY para tocar!");
            }
        });
    }

    public void playerPCMFeedBuffer(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void playerStarted() {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {            
            public void run() {
                ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
                loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ImageView playButton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Mais música brasileira");
            }           
        });     
    }

    public void playerStopped(int arg0) {
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable()  {            
            public void run() {
                activity.mp = null;
                activity.mp = new AACPlayer(new RadioCallBack(activity));
                ProgressBar loading = (ProgressBar) activity.findViewById(R.id.loadingAudio);
                loading.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                ImageView playButton = (ImageView) activity.findViewById(R.id.playButton);
                playButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((TextView)activity.findViewById(R.id.textView1)).setText("Pressione PLAY para tocar!");
            }           
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please put the XML File in your code. I need to play AACP streaming soon. Please help me out for that.

Comment: I want to play this stream : "http://stream2.servercristianonetwork.com:8072/"...Please please help me for that...

Comment: @DennySharma Sorry for the late comment, but if you're still looking for an answer: on your site you can download the m3u file. Those are easy to play, there's a ton of questions on stackoverflow on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

"to use a service" - right: android services grant your application components with additional running privileges that let them persist even when the component isn't on top of the task stack or even when your application is exited. Most of the times,excluding those critical resource-lacking situations, system won't interfere and stop the service so it's up to you how to control it.

Specifically for your case there's [an article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html#mpandservices) on the official site about building player with background playback capabilities. Yet they talk about MediaPlayer, same principles, I believe, hold for any custom player.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a Background service in order to make your Music player run in the background.

1st you will have to start the service. Then initialiize your MultiPlayer object in Service's onCreate() method.

Then implement ServiceConnection on your UI activity( Which has your Multiplayer UI).This will connect your UI Activity with Background service. Now you can Control the Background service and your Multiplayer object's e.g Play,Pause Functionality. Refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder) For implementing ServiceConnection.

You can also make your [serviceForground](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground) if you want the user to navigate back to ui by clicking on the notification in notification bar.

Hope this helps